# PostgreSQL query using json list of ids to second table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-json

I have a table column that contains a list of user ids in json format (the column type is character varying at the moment):

```
mydb=> select value.id, value.text from value where value.id=385283;
   id   |   text    
--------+-----------
 385283 | [2,3,4]
(1 row)
```

I have figured out that I can expand it using the following query:

```
mydb=> select value.id, json_array_elements(cast(value.text as json)) as user_id from value where value.id=385283;
   id   | user_id 
--------+---------
 385283 | 2
 385283 | 3
 385283 | 4
(3 rows)
```

Now I would like to retrieve the username from the user table, using the user ids returned by the previous query.

```
mydb=> select "user".username from "user" where "user".id in (2,3,4);
  username   
-------------
 Anonymous_2
 Anonymous_3
 Anonymous_4
```

I tried the query below (and several other ideas such as join, subquery) but I could not get it working:

```
mydb=> select "user".username from "user", value where value.id=385283 and "user".id in (json_array_elements(cast(value.text as json)));
ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE
LINE 1: ...r", value where value.id=385283 and "user".id in (json_array...
```

Please advise how I could write a query for this seemingly trivial problem.

Comment: " (the column type is character varying at the moment)"  Why are you putting off doing it right?  What are you waiting for?

Comment: The program supported only strings as data types at first. I then introduced more complex data types and converted the data to and from json in the java code. Now that I have learned that PostgreSQL directly supports json I will rewrite all queries accordingly and get rid of the java conversion code. Will also fix the table and column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using set-returning functions in the SELECT list is allowed, but generally a bad idea.  Put it in the FROM list.

```
select value.id, user_id, "user".username from 
   value CROSS JOIN  
   json_array_elements(cast(value.text as json)) f(user_id) JOIN
   "user" on "user".id=f.user_id
where value.id=385283;
```

Also, you should not use "user" or "value" as table names, or "text" as a column name.  Not even in examples.

Comment: Thanks, I got the code working with two minor changes:select value.id, user_id, "user".username from 
   value CROSS JOIN  
   json_array_elements_text(cast(value.text as json)) f(user_id) JOIN
   "user" on "user".id=f.user_id::int
where value.id=385283;